# Traefik Ingress Controller for Kubernetes (AWS EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, traefik, amazon-eks

I'm running my workloads on AWS EKS service in the cloud. I can see that there is not default Ingress Controller available (as it is available for GKE) we have to pick a 3rd party-one.

I decided to go with [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/). After following documentations and other resources (like [this](https://github.com/pahud/amazon-eks-workshop/tree/master/03-creating-services/ingress/traefik-ingress)), I feel that using Traefik as the Ingress Controller does not create a LoadBalancer in the cloud automatically. We have to go through it manually to setup everything.

How to use Traefik to work as the Kubernetes Ingress the same way other Ingress Controllers work (i.e. Nginx etc) that create a LoadBalancer, register services etc? Any working example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with annotations like in this example?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-proxy
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:REGION:ACCOUNTID:certificate/CERT-ID"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: traefik-proxy
    tier: proxy
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Here, It is of type `Service` where I feel that if I run `kubectl get ing`, it won't show Traefik as IC. Right?

Comment: The ingress is a set of rules, while ingress controller is usually a deamonset or deployment. So `kubectl get ing` won't show you anything but ingresses.

Comment: Ok so that means if we use Ingress Controller as DaemonSet or Deployment, `kubectl get ing` won't consider it as Ingress right? Moreover (In the post you provided), the `- host:` should have the value of k8s master node address (i.e. API Server Address something like `https://<some-id>.sk1.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com` provided by EKS?

Comment: Yes, host is the name of your registered app and is passed as field in HTTP header (it may be the name of your machine or if you have a registered domain, your DNS will point to the K8S master or better to the ELB, in case you have a HA cluster with more than a control plane).

Comment: Yep. Actually I find this `- host:` a bit curious. Since I'm using EKS where master nodes are managed for me by AWS. Only API Server Endpoint is provided by EKS. Which I'm supplying to `- host:` but it throws error. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178953/discussion-between-nicola-ben-and-janshair-khan).